# AG-GRID table carriage return feed avoids fixed rows

Tags: javascript

```
 <ag-grid-angular
    [style.width]="'100%'"
    [style.height]="scrollY"
    [class]="agThemeClass"
    [rowData]="dataList"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [localeText]="agGridLocaleText"
    [enterMovesDown]="true"
    [enterMovesDownAfterEdit]="true"
    (cellEditingStopped)="cellEditingStopped($event)"
    [pinnedBottomRowData]="rowDataBottom"
    [stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus]="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
    (cellKeyPress)="onCellKeyPress($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

[enterMovesDown]="true"    [enterMovesDownAfterEdit]="true"
To reach the return feed line, but will change to the bottom fixed total line, is there any way to avoid?